# Use gpu to draw on canvas

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, android-canvas

Are there any tools like fragment openGLES shaders, to draw on android canvas/bitmap? I need to calculate color of every pixel depends on it position, but it is very slow to work with bitmap as array. I can't use openGLES, because the result I have to get - bitmap. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you're looking for. The `Canvas` class has various methods to draw.

Comment: bylinear interpolation, to be exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to offload some heavy pixel manipulations to the GPU.

On Android, you have two major options:

1. OpenCL, but [OpenCL support on Android is cumbersome](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2014-06-30/opencl-support-recent-android-smartphones/)
2. [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html)

But don't underestimate the power that a CPU has, when you use vectorization instructions well. This might require hand-coding the vectorized loop using [NEON intrinsics](http://hilbert-space.de/?p=22), but it will be worth it. Note that the performance issues mentioned in this last link are all resolved.

Comment: Thanks! I tried RenderScript, and increased productivity more than 100 times.